# How to add specific template to a text

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a `xsl:template` and a `xsl:text`. I want to apply this template to text. I just changed param value to `"./asd:myNote"` but it doesn't work. Do I need to do something more?

My text:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./asd:myNote"/>
```

Here is my template:

```
<xsl:template name="filename-only">
    <xsl:param name="path" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($path, '\')">
            <xsl:call-template name="filename-only">
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after($path, '\')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$path" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `xsl:value-of` does not produce `xsl:text`. Do you mean: "I have a text node in my input XML"? It seems like the named template is for file paths - is `asd:myNote` a file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* (it's hard to be sure without seeing the context) that instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./asd:myNote"/>
```

you want to do:

```
<xsl:call-template name="filename-only">
    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="./asd:myNote"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

--

BTW, you have no "xsl:text". The `<xsl:text>` element is an element you would use in your stylesheet to write literal text to the output.